# Nestjs - schema.tree is undefined in mongoose model compilation output

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I'm new to Nest.js and using Mongoose and TypeScript in my project.
I'm doing everything as the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb) mentioned for using mongoose, except for one thing:

**UPDATE**: I tried it again exactly like the docs, still getting the same error.

In the docs, the db model schema is declared using a class:

```ts
// what the docs do:

import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = HydratedDocument<Cat>;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
  // schema
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

I declare it as an interface and mongoose `Schema` (according to the docs, it's OK to do this):

```ts
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { cat_interface } from '../interfaces/cat.schema';

// Cat is an interface with equal structue as this schema
export const CatSchema = new Schema<cat_interface>({
  // schema
});

// I guess this line is not needed as MongooseModule.forFeature() will do the modeling
// export const CatModel = model('Cat', CatSchema);
```

Here's the module and the service code:

```ts
// cat.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Cat', schema: CatSchema }])],
  controllers: [CatsController],
  providers: [CatService],
})
export class CatModule {}

// cat.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class CatService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Cat') protected readonly catsRepo: Model<cat_interface>,
  ) {}
}
```

Now, when I want to start the project, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')
```

[image: error details]

`tree` is a property of `CatModel.schema` (must be compiled by mongoose):

```ts
// node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js

Document.prototype.$__setSchema = function(schema) {
        /* ERROR HERE */
  compile(schema.tree, this, undefined, schema.options);

  // Apply default getters if virtual doesn't have any (gh-6262)
  for (const key of Object.keys(schema.virtuals)) {
    schema.virtuals[key]._applyDefaultGetters();
  }
  if (schema.path('schema') == null) {
    this.schema = schema;
  }
  this.$__schema = schema;
  this[documentSchemaSymbol] = schema;
};
```

Does anyone know, where the problem is? What am I doing wrong?

Packages:

- @nestjs/common `v10.0.0`
- @nestjs/mongoose `v10.0.1`
- mongoose `v7.4.3`